# Implement Google Analytics 4 in AMP

Tags: amp-html, google-analytics-4

I know that GA 4 is still not supported and the development under [ID #24621](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/24621) goes not further. They say GA4 should do the AMP part.
Universal Analytics will stopp at 1st July 2023 and I have a AMP only site.
Does anyone know an other solution to implement GA 4 as a workaround like via Tag-Manager?

Comment: I hope it helps https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics

Comment: @ShilaMosammami thanks but this is only for universal Analytics that will be canceld, not for the new GA4

Comment: my bad, sorry. have a look at this link https://www.thyngster.com/how-to-track-amp-pages-with-google-analytics-4